# Unlocked HTC One X (AT&T) Jelly Bean update

Tags: ota-update, htc-one-x

I just got my HTC One X from AT&T and have been using it unlocked on T-Mobile. Eventually, will I get the Jelly Bean update, or will I need to root?

Answer (score -1):

OTA updates come also with carrier modifications. So no, you will not

Comment: If you own a carrier branded device, then OTA updates come also with carrier modifications.